# SQL Server JSON_QUERY Select Json object based on value

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server-2019

I have the following JSON data in a SQL Server table:

```
{
    "Mapping": [
        {
            "SourceFieldId": 46,
            "TargetField": {
                "output_field_description": "Last Name",
                "output_header_field": "Last Name",
                "required": "Y",
                "data_type": "TEXT",
                "date_format": "",
                "number_of_decimals": "",
                "max_length": 30,
                "field": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "SourceFieldId": 46,
            "TargetField": {
                "output_field_description": "Last Name",
                "output_header_field": "Last Name",
                "required": "Y",
                "data_type": "TEXT",
                "date_format": "",
                "number_of_decimals": "",
                "max_length": 30,
                "field": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to grab the object based on the `SourceFieldID`.

I've tried a few variations of this, with no luck:

```
SELECT
    JSON_query(MapJSON, '$.Mapping')  
FROM
    MapHistories 
WHERE
    JSON_VALUE(MapJSON, '$.Mapping.SourceFieldID') = 1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you edit your question and tag the DBMS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16) to parses the json as the first argument and returns one or more rows containing data from the JSON objects  :

```
SELECT SalesOrderJsonData.*
FROM MapHistories AS Tab
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Tab.MapJSON, N'$.Mapping') WITH (
    SourceFieldId int N'$.SourceFieldId',
    TargetField nvarchar(max) N'$.TargetField' AS JSON 
    ) AS SalesOrderJsonData
where SalesOrderJsonData.SourceFieldId = 46
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/apBImjSu)